# How to switch between a binary number as String and a as a list of digits?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I was trying with String Functions and I viewing any posts and have no results

I want to know

1.- From

```
cromo33 = Table[RandomInteger[], {i, 1, 33}]
cromo33
```

that gives {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,......,1,0,0} , alist of 33 elements

How can you obtain "1011101.....100" ?

2.- From

```
IntegerString[RandomInteger[8], 2] // InputForm
```

that gives 101    (a little add-on... ¿how can I force this to obtain 4 digits in any random number?)

How can you obtain a list {1,0,1} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are built-in functions to play:

```
NumberForm[FromDigits@RandomInteger[1, 5], 6, NumberPadding -> "0"]
```

> ```
> "0011101"
> ```

---

Or very straightforward approach:

#### 1

```
RandomInteger[1, 5]
PadLeft[%, 7]
ToString /@ %
StringJoin@%
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}
> {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}
> {"0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0"}
> "0001010"
> ```

#### 2

```
IntegerString[RandomInteger[8], 2]
Characters@%
PadLeft[%, 4]
ToExpression@%
```

> ```
> "101"
> {"1", "0", "1"}
> {0, "1", "0", "1"}
> {0, 1, 0, 1}
> ```

Comment: I love this kind of answers, with multiple and simply solutions. Thanks

Comment: The only option I miss is from "101" to 101, and viceversa.

Comment: @MikaIke It's `ToExpression` and `ToString` :) And thanks, I'm glad you like it :)

Answer (score 4):

Just  some other functions to consider:

- `IntegerDigits` an take a base argument, e.g. `IntegerDigits[5,2]` yields {1,0,1}
- `FromDigits` is the inverse: `FromDigits[{1,0,1},2]` yields 5
- If the issue is for display purpose and not specifically  need for strings then `BaseForm` will display binary numbers with subscript of 2, i.e.`BaseForm[5,2]` yields: $101_2$
- so for first part if display is aim you can use (perhaps somewhat perversely) `BaseForm[ToExpression@Table[RandomInteger[], {i, 1, 33}]]`

Comment: is for work with cromosomas en genetic algorithms

Comment: @MikaIke thank you for clarification. All the best in your endeavours.

Comment: Thank you, it´s my final project in maths grade/degree

Answer (score 1):

Let:

```
SeedRandom[11]

cromo33 = RandomInteger[1, 33];
```

To produce your string I would use [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html) and [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html):

```
ToString @ Row @ cromo33
```

> ```
> "001101111011110111010011001000101"
> ```

For the second case [`IntegerString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerString.html) takes a third parameter that specifies length:

```
SeedRandom[15]
string = IntegerString[RandomInteger[8], 2, 4]
```

> ```
> "0101"
> ```

To convert this back into to a digit list I propose [`ToCharacterCode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToCharacterCode.html):

```
ToCharacterCode[string] - 48
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 0, 1}
> ```