# Printing the base 'b' value of an integer as a string (without the subscript base indication)

Tags: output-formatting

Is there a simple one-liner to convert a given base 10 integer to a string representation of this integer in some desired base 'b'?  Is there a way to do this avoiding the subscript indicating the base, for example the small 2 if we ask for a binary string?

The best thing for my purpose, despite the danger, would be have a function that takes a decimal integer and returns what appears to be the binary, ternary, etc. representation of this integer, but which Mathematica still treats as a decimal integer value.

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44440/5478)

Answer (score 3):

There's a built-in to do just this, e.g.:

```
IntegerString[125, 2]
IntegerString[125, 16]

(*
1111101
7d
*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringJoin @@ ToString /@ IntegerDigits[105, 3]
```

> ```
> "10220"
> ```

```
FromDigits[ToExpression@Characters[%], 3]
```

> ```
> 105
> ```

Comment: @Kuba: can you point me to a FAQ where I can learn the standards of prefered layout?

Comment: Here's the [markdown info](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). But about "output" there isn't best way. this is the one I'm using :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a function that, for example takes the number fifteen and the base two, writes 15 in base 2 (which is 1111) and then returns the value one thousand, eleventy one (base 10).

If that's what you're aiming at, then what you are looking for is

```
f[number_, base_] := FromDigits[IntegerDigits[number, base]]
```

where base says what the intermediate base you want to filter your number through should be.

```
(* 
In[2]:= f[15, 2]

Out[2]= 1111
*)
```